# Injecting namespaces in functions in clojure

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to inject namespaces in a function in Clojure?

I want my i/o to be outside from the program and only inject it. The problem i faced, that i tried to give a namespace and invoke it i get the error message:

> ```
> No name namespace: my
> ```

```
(ns mymain
  (:require [myio]))

...

(defn my-test [my]
  (my/showworld))

;(play_game)
(my-test myio)
```

Comment: My guess would be, that you need `ns-resolve`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to pass logic is through functions and not by namespace aliases:

```
(defn my-test [show-world]
  (show-world))

(require 'myio)
(my-test myio/show-world)
```

Comment: how do you create a mock object for your namespace?

Comment: You usually don't mock namespaces, but you can mock functions e.g. with with-redefs.